# Regexp for returning any combination of two sequential items on a list

Tags: regex

My input is like

```
aa,bb,cc,dd
```

I'd like to obtain

```
aa,bb
bb,cc
cc,dd
```

So far, I learned about lazy and greedy operators but also lookahead assertions.

```
(?=([^,]+,[^,]+))
```

But I keep getting more matches than expected. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why would you want to use a RegExp on this? If it's a list, split it by `,` and work with it like a list, not like a string.

Comment: Because it is not an split but an overlapped match

Comment: @mdsl hes looking for all the consecutive pairs of elements.

Comment: @user1352530, check out my answer. It solves your problem without using regex

Comment: How are those reasons not to use a list? If anything, it's an argument not to use RegExps. Reuse is much easier with a list (`a[i], a[i+1]`) than with a RegExp.

Comment: `(?=(\b[^,]+\b,\b[^,]+\b))`

Comment: User887675 thanks a lot. If you edit that comment as an answer I give you the check! That's the best solution as it does not need substitution even. I only needed to learn to use word boundaries, as the rest of the regex is what I already came with

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(?=(\b[^,]+\b,\b[^,]+\b))
```

Demo: http://regex101.com/r/zJ4mA9

Comment: I think inner \b are not even needed after testing it a while

Answer (score 3):

I second @mdsl's comment about not using regular expressions, but I quickly whipped something up that should work.

```
(?=(?!^)\b[^,]+,)([^,]+)\K
\n\1
```

**Demo:** [RegEx](http://regex101.com/r/fG4zM4) or [PHP](http://ideone.com/KU7gaJ)

---

**Explanation:**

```
(?=     (?# start lookahead)
 (?!^)  (?# negative lookahead for the start of the string)
 \b     (?# assert for word boundary)
 [^,]+  (?# match 1+ non-, characters)
 ,      (?# match ,)
)       (?# end lookahead)
(       (?# start capture group)
 [^,]+  (?# match 1+ non-, characters)
)       (?# end capture group)
\K      (?# throw away everything to the left)
```

The big thing here is that the lookahead does not actually match anything, meaning we can overlap our matches (`aa,bb`, `bb,cc`, etc).  Because of this lookahead, it will put a line break in right after the first group `aa`..this is what the `(?!^)` assertion is for.  However, now it will split the `aa` in half unless we make sure that the `[^,]+` group is preceded by a word boundary (you see how this got kind of hairy kind of quick).  Finally `\K` is use to throw everything away, since we don't actually want to replace anything.

Comment: How do you know he's using a flavor that supports `\K`?  There aren't many that do.  Also, `(?!^)` is a negative **lookahead**, not lookbehind.  (It works either way; I'm just correcting the terminology.)

Comment: Good catch @AlanMoore, and I don't know that his flavor supported `\K`.  I kind of just went with it, since OP should've specified..if it was marked as accepted I would work on a more universal solution.

Answer (score 2):

```
[^,]+\,[^,]+
```

`[^,]+` Checks for the next token that doesn't contain commas; the next char after must be a comma (or the end of the initial string)

`\,` captures the comma,

`[^,]+` captures the next token after.

Comment: Thanks, that is what I already come with, my problem is the overlapping grouping